# Accesing Object from collection VB

Tags: vb.net

i'm developing a drugstore system as a task in college, it is a three layer architecture and i have a problem accesing data from a collection.

How can i access specific data from a collection?. E.g.:

```
If _pat.dao.Patients.Item(1).Equals(patientID) Then
        idcat = _pat.PatCategory
End If
```

The collection is full with patient objects each one with its own attributes(ID, name ....)

```
_pat.dao.Patients
```

basically retrieves the whole collection, and i'm trying to find the object where the ID fits patientID to get the category from that object. I don't properly know how the Item property works and i dont' know if the Item(1) is retrievieng the first object of the collection or the first attribute of every object. Any help on this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What kind of collection is it (how is it declared) and what is in it (looks like Patient objects).  *Generally* `Patients(0)` (or `Patients.Item(0)`) will give you the first entire first item (object), then `Patients(0).Id` would be the Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `FirstOrDefault` collection extension method to locate the patient:

```
Dim patient = _pat.dao.Patients.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.ID = patientID)
```

If the patient is found it will be returned to the `patient` variable. If it's not found the `patient` variable will be null, which in VB.NET is `Nothing`:

```
If patient IsNot Nothing Then
  idcat = patient.PatCategory
End If
```